# Can we provide two entry points for single page application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, single-page-application

I am working on a Single Page Application. Our first page is login page where we enter username and password.

Now client gave us a new requirement to provide a seperate login page for admin users. There should be an extra drop down list in Admin Login page.

They need two URLs for our app. One for Admin users and one for normal users.

As far as i know, we cannot add two HTML page in single page application. Only the inner view can be changed. But how can i identify the which login view should be displayed.

I couldn't figure out a way to do this. Please provide any guidance.

Comment: I'd have two separate URLs - take advantage of REST.

Comment: Wouldn't that just be another html/php/whatever page with the same js includes, but knowing your on the different page so you can provide the dropdown?

Comment: What options do you have available currently?

Comment: since it is a single page application, we have only index.html as entry point now

Comment: I am unsure how you would do this with a single page.  The issue is, without additional information, you have no way of knowing a visitor is going to try to login as an admin or not.  Two pages would allow for the distinction.  Otherwise, you'd need some sort of identifier on the page that the user could select to tell the page that they are going to try to login as an admin.  But that would be visible to ordinary users, which is most likely not a good idea.

Comment: That is exactly the issue which i am facing

Comment: Thus us suggesting an additional page for the admins.  index.html for normal users, admin.html for admins.  They can both use the same js includes, but the admin.html could include something extra to identify itself to the js that it is the admin version, and proceed accordingly.

Comment: As far as i know, we cannot add another html page for single page application. Only inner view can be changed. But how can i identify which view to be displayed? :(

Comment: You could maayyybe do this: if you are admin press ctrl + click on login: and add a condition with jquery like: when x button is clicked: if (ctrlKey) { admin } else { user }

Comment: But we are building mobile website. Target devices are ipad and iphone.

Comment: For admins too? Maybe admins could log in just as a normal user, but when an admin account logs in redirect him to another site? I have no idea D:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a dynamic router for login route like this:

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        "login/:id":        "login"  // #login/user or #login/admin
    },
    login: function(id, page) {
        if(id === "user"){
            //render user login view
        }else if(id === "admin"){
            //render admin login view
        }
    }

});
```

**UPDATE**

This is the [link](http://backbonejs.org/#Router)

Comment: I have a doubt regarding your answer. I am new to backbone.js. Currently, when i am giving `App/index.html` in browser, we are routing to `control/login/showLoginView`. Can we provide two URLs for same app?

Comment: Single page app works on hash tag so, yes you can have as many routes you want. Those routes depend on your functionality. You can have route for normal user like this : 'control/login/showUserLoginView' and for admin : 'control/login/showAdminLoginView'.

Comment: I agree on this approach. We can give two urls like `App.index.html/#control/login/showUserLoginView` and `App.index.html/#control/login/showAdminLoginView`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code as per my project framework.

I gave the following during app initialization:

```
var mode = location.hash.substring(1).toLowerCase();
if (mode == "admin") {
    sessionStorage.isAdmin = true;
}
else {
    sessionStorage.isAdmin = false;
}
```

While rendering view i gave following code:

```
if (sessionStorage.isAdmin == "true") {
    var template = _.template(adminTemplate);
}
else {
    var template = _.template(loginTemplate);
}
```

I hope this apporach is correct :)